# Batch File - How to get the value of an array with variable index?

Tags: arrays, batch-file, indexing

I'm trying to set a variable with the value from an array in a batch file, but no solution seems to work so far. Here's a snippet of the situation:

```
:: random value
set ParId=123

:: get the last number of the previous value
set /a "temp0=%ParId% %% 10"

:: part of my array, just for the example
set AsciiNumTable[0]=0x30
set AsciiNumTable[1]=0x31
set AsciiNumTable[2]=0x32
set AsciiNumTable[3]=0x33
set AsciiNumTable[4]=0x34
set AsciiNumTable[5]=0x35
set AsciiNumTable[6]=0x36
set AsciiNumTable[7]=0x37
set AsciiNumTable[8]=0x38
set AsciiNumTable[9]=0x39

:: PART NOT WORKING
set ParIdByte0=AsciiNumTable[%temp0%]
```

I've tried different methods:

```
call set ParIdByte0=%AsciiNumTable[!tempId5!]%
```

but they also do not work.

If I output the array and the temp variable they look fine, so I don't know why I can't get the value from the array.

Comment: Basically you have to make sure that the "inner" variable (the one holding the index) becomes expanded before the "outer" one (the array variable itself)...

Comment: This management is fully explained at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in a reverse approach you are trying (with using delayed expansion).THough there are few more issues with your script 1)Missing set keyword when assigning value to `ParId` 2) `temp0` value will be `3` and you have no third element in the array:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:: random value
set ParId=123

:: get the last number of the previous value
set /a "temp0=%ParId% %% 10"

:: part of my array, just for the example
set AsciiNumTable[0]=0x30
set AsciiNumTable[1]=0x31
set AsciiNumTable[2]=0x32
set AsciiNumTable[3]=0x33

:: PART NOT WORKING
set ParIdByte0=!AsciiNumTable[%temp0%]!

echo --%ParIdByte0%--
```

Comment: Hi! This works just fine. I had tried different combinations for the last 'set', but not the one you suggested. Also, I just tried to quickly replicate the code here, that's why some stuff is missing, I'll improve it so it looks better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"do not work" is meaningless. Please state what you expect and what actually happened.

Try

```
call set ParIdByte0=%%AsciiNumTable[%temp0%]%%
```

Comment: Hi! The issue was that ParIdByte0 was not receiving any value, but the solution from npocmaka worked fine. I tried your approach, but unfortunately it didn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: "Not work" is still meaningless. Your original code had `temp0` set to `3` but had not set that array value. Did you try this approach in your modified code?

Comment: Hi. I think it is pretty clear that ParIdByte0 was not getting any value, as npocmaka noted, hence "not working". The original post had only a rough transcription (which contained mistakes). Using the approach from the other answer solved the issue. Thanks.